# how use FragmentTransaction from array adapter to fragment

Tags: java, android, bundle

when i pass parameter between `array adapter` and  `fragment`, the value of string user it is not print in log...why????

This is my code:

ARRAY ADAPTER:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

{

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context ;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;
    public boolean Checked;
    private Integer[] imageId;
    String ciao;

   /* public PlanetAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
    }
*/

 public PlanetAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Planet> planetList, Context context,Integer[] imageId) {


    super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item,planetList);


    this.fm=fm;
    this.planetList = planetList;
    this.context = context;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}






    public class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public TextView caratteristica;
        public boolean checked;
        public TextView id;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Spinner spinner;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);

            holder.caratteristica=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caratteristica);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);


            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.caratteristica.setText(p.getCaratteristica());
       holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
        SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = states.getBoolean("holder.chkBox" + holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
        System.out.println(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(true);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            SharedPreferences statess = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String string = statess.getString("finalHolder.edit" + holder.planetName.getText().toString(), holder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
            holder.edit.setText(string);


        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


         }

        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(PlanetAdapter.this);
       // final BirraHolder finalHolder = birraHolder;
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;

        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            getContext(),
                            R.array.country_arrays,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    //finalHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        finalHolder.spinner.setSelection(position);
                        String selState = finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        System.out.println(selState);
                        Toast.makeText(
                        getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("key", selState);
                            Log.i("BUNDLE", bundle.toString());
                            //fragment.setArguments(bundle);


                            //frag.setArguments(bundleUp);
                            String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
                            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
                            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
                            ft.commit();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }






                    });
                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                    editor.commit();
                    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                            editor.putString("finalHolder.edit" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            editor.commit();


                        }
                    });

                  /*  SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                    editor.commit();*/
                    //Utility.putPizzaItem(p);
                    //Utility.getPizzaItem(p);


                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }

            }
        });
        /*holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox", true);
                    //pizzaSelected.put(p.getId(), p);
                    System.out.println(p.getId());
                } else {

                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText(null);
                    pizzaSelected.remove(p.getId());

                }

            }
        });
*/


       /* finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                editor.putString("finalHolder.edit" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.commit();


            }
        });
*/

       // holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
       // holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
       // holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
       // holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
       // holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
       // holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
        //  holder.id.setId(p.getId());

        return row;
    }




    private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
        return null;
    }


    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.isSelected())
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }



    }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
     public  class MyListFragment extends Fragment{

    String user="";


        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
                if (arguments != null) {
                        //String userId = arguments.getString("key");
                        //System.out.println("finalmente:"+userId);
                     user = arguments.getString("key");


                } /*else {
                    Log.i("BUNDLE == null", "NULL");
                }*/
                System.out.println("finalmente:"+user);
.
.
.
planetList.add(new Planet(getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(),"Margherita", "6", "€","(pomodoro e mozzarella),"));
    planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", "7","€","(pomodoro,mozzarella e salsiccia piccante)"));
    planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", "5","€","(pomodoro e mozzarella di bufala)"));
    planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", "5", "€","(pomodoro)"));
    planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", "4", "€", "(pomodoro,mozzarella e wrustel)"));

    plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),planetList, getContext(),imageId)
```

Comment: `if (getArguments() != null)` check if exexution is passing this `if` condition in code..

Comment: repalce getArguments() with this.getArguments();

Comment: @SuryaBondada where .getArguments();?

Comment: no.............same problem.....

Comment: execution don't enter into if condition

Comment: the above code should be in onCreate()

Comment: yes, it is in onCreateView()

Comment: i miss commit?? into first fragment?

Comment: add `arg = this.getArguments();`

Comment: Try removing `final` from `bundle`.

Comment: @Sanoop where????????????

Comment: `Bundle arguments = this.getArguments();`

Comment: @Ifly6 i tried to remove final but i have same problem

Comment: @Sanoop i put Bundle arguments = this.getArguments(); but i have same problem

Comment: Can you post the code snippet for `FragmentTransaction` you are using?

Comment: i not using FragmentTransaction....i must use it? if yes how is the syntax?

Comment: then how are you moving from one Fragment to other?

Comment: XD....so how i must write code?

Comment: i missing FragmentTransaction....but how i must use FragmentTransaction?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [mcve], not snippets of code that we have to guess what you're trying to do. You've gotten so many comments that are not constructive already.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however, that is not *minimal*

Comment: @il_lupo Is Fragment fragment = new Fragment(); a typo error ?? Since MyListFragment is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some useful methods to help break apart your logic.

```
public Fragment buildFragment(String data) {
    MyListFragment fragment = new MyListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", data);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
} 

// Display Fragment in a View with ID of "menu_frame" 
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getContextFragmentManager(this.context);
    fm.beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.menu_frame, fragment) // Make sure this ID can be found in the XML for the activity 
       .addToBackStack(tag)
       .commit();
} 

// Helper method to get the FragmentManager within the adapter 
public FragmentManager getContextFragmentManager(Context context) {
    FragmentManager fm = null;
    if(context instanceof Activity){
        fm = ((Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    return fm;
}
```

How you receive the argument in the Fragment looks fine.

You should be able to use these methods like so

```
finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        finalHolder.spinner.setSelection(position);
        String selState = finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Fragment fragment = buildFragment(selState);

        String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
        replaceFragment(fragment, tag);
 }
```

---

Notes:

When inside the adapter, there is no `getActivity()` method in an Adapter, so you must cast the context.

And `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()` ultimately depends which Fragment class you're using - the Support v4 Fragment or the `android.app.Fragment` class

Please **delete** this method from the Adapter.

```
private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager(); is written in red by IDE

Comment: i must add an id to my layout?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager is written in red by IDE again

Comment: could you write a clean code? without modify the code write before?

Comment: Please delete your method `getSupportFragmentManager` that explicitly returns null...

Comment: Is anything unclear now? I believe this code is clean, by the way. Isolated methods are more preferred than laying out all your code into just one method like you've done in your Adapter class

Comment: Please help me help you by explaining exactly what isn't working for you

Comment: this code is not correct to pass parameter from adapter to fragment

Comment: Please explain why `fragment.setArguments(bundle);` is incorrect

Comment: No offense, but I understand if English isn't your main language, so try to form a complete explanation of the problem with the code I've provided. I cannot foresee any errors with what I've shown.

Comment: That's a problem with your code, not mine. I wrote methods that you need to copy into the adapter class. Not into another method. The "sample" code that I provide closely matches code that you already have. So, I suggest you get your code to a working state with no red errors. And maybe even start over with a **simple** adapter